# Why does PowerShell intermittently not find List[string].Add() method?

Tags: powershell

I've got a build script (PowerShell 4 on Windows 2012 R2) that runs NUnit in a background job and returns NUnit's output.  This output is collected in a `Collections.Generic.List[string]`.

```
$nunitJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
                                    param(
                                        [string]
                                        $BinRoot,

                                        [string]
                                        $NUnitConsolePath,

                                        [string[]]
                                        $NUnitParams,

                                        [string]
                                        $Verbose
                                    )

                                    Set-Location -Path $BinRoot
                                    $VerbosePreference = $Verbose

                                    Write-Verbose -Message ('{0} {1}' -f $NUnitConsolePath,($NUnitParams -join ' '))
                                    & $NUnitConsolePath $NUnitParams 2>&1 
                                    $LASTEXITCODE
                                 } -ArgumentList $binRoot,$nunitConsolePath,$nunitParams,$VerbosePreference

$nunitJob | Wait-Job -Timeout ($timeoutMinutes * 60) | Out-Null
$jobKilled = $false
if( $nunitJob.JobStateInfo.State -eq [Management.Automation.JobState]::Running )
{
    $jobKilled = $true
    $errMsg = 'Killing {0} tests: exceeded {1} minute timeout.' -f $assembly.Name,$timeoutMinutes
    Write-Error -Message $errMsg
}

$output = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[string]'

$nunitJob | 
    Stop-Job -PassThru | 
    Receive-Job |
    ForEach-Object  { 
        if( -not $_ )
        {
            [void]$output.Add( '' )
            return
        }

        switch -Regex ( $_ )
        {
            '^Tests run: (\d+), Errors: (\d+), Failures: (\d+), Inconclusive: (\d+), Time: ([\d\.]+) seconds$'
            {
                $testsRun = $Matches[1]
                $errors = $Matches[2]
                $failures = $Matches[3]
                $inconclusive = $Matches[4]
                $duration = New-Object 'TimeSpan' 0,0,$Matches[5]
                break
            }
            '^  Not run: (\d+), Invalid: (\d+), Ignored: (\d+), Skipped: (\d+)$'
            {
                $notRun = $Matches[1]
                $invalid = $Matches[2]
                $ignored = $Matches[3]
                $skipped = $Matches[4]
                break
            }
        }

        # Error happens here:
        [void] $output.Add( $_ )
    }
```

Intermittently, our build will fail with this error:

> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
>                      At line:XXXXX char:XXXXX
>                      +                                     [void] $output.Add( $_ )
>                      +                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                          + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>                          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

***Any idea why PowerShell would not be able to find `List[string]`'s `Add` method?***

I've opened a console Window and played around with passing different typed objects to `Add` without getting an error.

```
> $o = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[string]'
> $o.Add( '' )
> $o.Add( $null )
> $o.Add( 1 )
> $o


1
```

Comment: Problem is most likely that it cannot implicitly convert `$_` to a string. Like `$o.Add($(New-Object psobject))`

Comment: @zespri I did remove some lines, but none that involved `$output`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That may be it. I tried `$output.Add( [pscustomobject]@{ } )` and am able to reproduce the error. Now I have to figure out why PowerShell isn't treating console output as strings.

Comment: "treating console output as strings"? Do you attempt to modify `$_` in any way during foreach-object? Again, the entire code block might be useful/meaningful here.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just added the code that starts the background NUnit job. Looks like that script block is returning things PowerShell can't convert to a string. Not sure what that could be.

Comment: It might be worth adding a `Write-Verbose $_.GetType().Fullname -Verbose` just to see what kind of object you are dealing with.

Comment: @boeprox Already added. The fix is easy: just explicitly call ToString() on each object added to the list. But before I do, I have to know what kind of object is throwing a kink in the works.

Comment: `switch` has really odd behavior in powershell, it's not a cmdlet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721593/powershell-set-psdebug-trace-2-causes-unexpected-results

Comment: @Aaron Jensen Yep, using ToString() will definitely be the easy fix. You could also use `Set-PSBreakPoint` on `[void] $output.Add( $_ )` so you can then inspect the object.

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect stderr to stdout, you can get System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecords interspersed with strings. Stderr is automatically converted to ErrorRecords while stdout is strings.

So you'll probably want to look to see if the output contains ErrorRecords of interest and if not then filter them out.